# Make a Material UI GridList containing images into background

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a GridList with a bunch of images that I am retrieving from an external service. This is used to create an image gallery. These images are updated regularly so the image gallery looks different every time.

How do I turn the image gallery into grayscale or even make it transparent and then use it as a background so that I can put content on top of the image gallery? I want to be able to put text boxes, images on top of the image gallery.

This is what I have so far

```
<GridList cols={3}>
{
this.state.images.map(image => (
      <GridListTile
        rows={1}
        ref={this.imageRef}
        key={image.id}
        style={{ padding: 0 }}
      >
        <img src={image.urls.regular} alt={image.alt_description} />
      </GridListTile>
    ))
}
</GridList>
```

This is what my UI looks like at the moment:
[image]

My issue is with the `Hello World` text. As you can see from the image, it is at the bottom left. I'd like to put that text in the center and turn the GridList of the image into the background that either transparent or grey scaled.

My end goal is to be able to add other Material UI components on top of the GridList of images. Essentially I wand the GrdList of images to act as background so that I can place other content o top of it.

I've tried adding `z-index` to the components with no look

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or an online demo to explain what's your demand in detail?

Comment: @keikai I've updated with an image and description of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @breaktop maybe you can try using `z-index` in css for the `GridList` ?

Comment: @breaktop and then find a way to center the Hello world text in center...

Comment: @DonaldWu I've tried adding z-index's onto the components and haven't had any look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep both `GridList` and "Hello world" in same `Box` container provided by `material-ui`, and by using `Box` container's props you can center "Hello World".

Try This

```
<Box position="relative" >
    <GridList cols={3}>
    {
       this.state.images.map(image => (
          <GridListTile
            rows={1}
            ref={this.imageRef}
            key={image.id}
            style={{ padding: 0 }}
          >
            <img src={image.urls.regular} alt={image.alt_description} />
          </GridListTile>
        ))
    }
    </GridList>

    <Box position="absolute" top="50%" align="center" width="100%" zIndex={1}>
        <Typography>Hello World</Typography>
    </Box>

</Box>
```

I hope it helps